# An example of function s.t. $f=f(x,t)$ continuous but not $t\mapsto \int_E f(x,t)dx$

Tags: integration

Do you have an example of function s.t. $f:I\times E\to \mathbb R$ continuous ($I$ and $E$ are interval) but $$t\longmapsto \int_E f(x,t)dx$$
is not continuous. I suppose that a necessary condition is that $E$ and $I$ are not bounded, otherwise if they are bounded, $f$ is bounded (let say by $M$) and $x\longmapsto M$ is integrable over $E$ and thus the conclusion follow by DCT.

I was thinking about something as $$\int_0^\infty e^{-xt}dt$$ for $x\geq 0$, but unfortunately, for $x=0$ the integral doesn't converge.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\sin{tx}}{x} \, dx = \begin{cases} \pi & t>0 \\ 0 & t=0 \\ -\pi & t<0 \end{cases} $$
This is sometimes called Dirichlet's discontinuous integral.

It's quite easy to come up with such integrals using Fourier transforms: another one is
$$ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x\sin{kx}}{1+x^2} \, dx = \pi e^{-|k|} \begin{cases} 1 & k>0 \\ 0 & k=0 \\ -1 & k<0 \end{cases}. $$

Comment: Just : If $t=0$, it's not defined, is it ? (because $\int_{-\infty }^\infty \frac{1}{x}dx$ doesn't converge.

Comment: In both of them now, the integrand vanishes identically when the non-integration variable is zero.